# Generalization of Banach algebra for Sobolev spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, banach-algebras

It is well-known that if $k\in\mathbb{N}$

\begin{equation}
\|u^k\|_{H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)}\leq \|u\|_{H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)}^k \ \ \text{for all}  \ \ m> \frac{d}{2}+1
\end{equation}
by the property of Banach algebra of Sobolev space. Then
I have a question. We assume that $u\leq0$. If $s\geq 1$
\begin{equation}
\|u^s\|_{H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)}\leq \|u\|_{H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)}^s \ \ \text{for all}  \ \ m>\frac{d}{2}+1
\end{equation}
Is the above statement also true?
If this is true, show me the proof, please.

Comment: What do you mean by $u^s$? Perhaps $\lvert u\rvert^s$? You can't take a non-integer power of a nonpositive number and $u$ can take any value in general

Comment: I edit my question according to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: The Banach algebra property you mention is valid as soon as $H^m \hookrightarrow L^\infty$, which, in $\mathbb{R}^d$, occurs as soon as $m > d/2$ (you don't need the +1).

Comment: Replace $u$ by $u^{1/k}$ in your first inequality and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\frac{d}{2} < m < s$. Then, for any $u \in H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)$, there holds:
$$
\| |u|^s \|_{H^m} \lesssim \| u \|_{H^m} \| u \|_{L^\infty}^{s-1}.
$$
This is a particular case of [Runst and Sickel - *Sobolev spaces of fractional order, Nemytskij operators, and nonlinear partial differential equations.* de Gruyter, 1996, Section 5.4.3, Theorem 1], which is itself a particular case of more general question: when is $G(u) \in H^m$ for some arbitrary function $G$? Here $G(\cdot) = |\cdot|^s$.

When $s < m$, there might be some difficulties. Take for example $d = 1$ and $u(t) := t \chi(t)$ where $\chi$ is some smooth compactly supported function, with $\chi \equiv 1$ near 0. When $s = \frac{3}{2}$, near $t = 0$, $|u(t)|^s = t^{3/2}$, so in particular $u''(t) = \frac{3}{4} t^{-1/2}$ for $0 < t \ll 1$, so $u \notin H^2$ locally.

In my counter example, $u$ changes sign. It is possible that, in your particular setting with the *a priori* assumption that $u \geq 0$, you can avoid this pathological case. I have not given it much thought.